# How can I create a pair RDD from an RDD of single elements in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Here is the actual pipeline. I'm loading text to RDD. I then clean it up.

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile("sometext.txt")

import re
import string

def Func(lines):
    lines = lines.lower() #make all text lowercase
    lines = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', lines) #remove punctuation
    lines = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', lines) #remove numeric-containing strings
    lines = lines.split() #split lines
    return lines
rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap(Func)

stopwords = ['list of stopwords goes here'] 
rdd3 = rdd2.filter(lambda x: x not in stopwords) # filter out stopwords
rdd3.take(5) #resulting RDD

Out:['a',
     'b',
     'c',
     'd',
     'e']
```

I need to do now is the start of a Markov Chain function. I want to pair up each element with its consecutive element such as:

[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), etc...]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the order of element in your RDD to determine how 2 elements are considered "consecutive" to each other. Because your RDD can consists of multiple partitions, so spark won't know if 1 element in partition_1 is consecutive to another element in partition_2.

If you know your data well in advance, you can define the key and also how 2 elements are "consecutive". Given your example where rdd is created from list, you could use the index as key and do a join.

```
"""you want to shift arr by 1 to the left, then join back to arr. Calculation based on index"""

arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
rdd = sc.parallelize(arr, 2).zipWithIndex().cache() #cache if rdd is small 

original_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])) #create rdd with key=index, value=item in list

shifted_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1]-1, x[0]))

results = original_rdd.join(shifted_rdd)
print(results.values().collect())
```

To achieve better performance in `join`, you can use a range partitions for `original_rdd` and `shifted_rdd`.

Comment: Thank you @dtth. If I was doing it in Python I would make an iterative function to couple each element in the list with one that follows it (x[n], x[n+1]). But I cannot perform iterative actions like that on an RDD.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't perform iterative actions"? I don't really get it. Could you clarify?

Comment: I meant that I tried and got a traceback that said that RDD object is not iterative. I can try again to paste the exact error message.

Comment: Maybe I can do a key-value pair of each element as key and the element that follows it as a value?

Comment: I edited my question to show the actual pipeline. When I use the process, you suggested I get the following error: "TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable"

Comment: Hmm, don't know why you get the err. It worked well for me. So after your code, you use my suggested method:
``` rdd= rdd3.zipWithIndex() 
original_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])) 
shifted_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1]-1, x[0]))
results = original_rdd.join(shifted_rdd)
print(results.values().collect()) ```

Comment: we need to have zipWithIndex to use index as key, and the word is the value. Then join back. This would work, but not efficient. to make it more efficient, perhaps you should use range partition for join. Btw, do you know why there is the downvote?

Comment: Thank you @dtth. I will try that. No idea about the downvote. Your method works as a standalone. However, I think there is something about the way my RDD comes out of a pipeline that is the issue?

Comment: Not sure. Your rdd3 looks like a normal valid RDD to me. You can debug and see what happens there :D

Comment: It worked! I don't know what happened the first time around. Maybe I needed to rerun the previous code (doing it in Jupyter in portions.) Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked in the end. As I said, for performance, you can consider using range partition as a common partitioner. Good luck :+1:

Comment: smart solution!

Answer (score -1):

Pretty descent approach. Can really be optimized much more.

```
>>> rdd=sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
#zipping with Index to rip off odd and even elements, to group consecutive elements in future
>>> rdd_odd=rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (x,y):y%2!=0).map(lambda (x,y):x).coalesce(1)
>>> rdd_even=rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (x,y):y%2==0).map(lambda (x,y):x).coalesce(1)
>>> rdd_2=rdd_even.zip(rdd_odd)
>>> rdd_2.collect()
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

Ensure to have even number of elements in `rdd_1`. That will actually form the base for pairing consecutive elements.

Comment: Thank you @Jim Todd. I actually need each element with it's consecutive element. Meaning, I need [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c',' d'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'f'),...]